# Magento 1.9.x - Add class="{{title}}" to CustomOptions frontend Output

Tags: custom

Looking for a way to add the Product > Custom Options > Select Option "Title" also as class to the same option entry.

Default Custom Options Select Frontend Output:

```
<select>
 <option value="1">Title</option>
</select>
```

What I'm after...:

```
<select>
 <option value="1" class="Title">Title</option>
</select>
```

No need for an additional admin field + DB entry. If the title is used as input for the .class name would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: I've tried adding the classname directly into the DB; without success - something not working out...
http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564542/magento-custom-options-add-a-css-classname-to-the-custom-option-field

Comment: thanks - I tried to add it within Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option - but this isn't working... Also I don't really need a Custom Entry per Option. The Title should be also the class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Follow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564542/magento-custom-options-add-a-css-classname-to-the-custom-option-field

Or copy magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\select.php to your local and replace this:

```
 $select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . '',
                    array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false))
                );
```

With:

```
$select->addOption(
                   $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                   $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . '',
                    array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false), 'class' => '$_value->getTitle()')
                );
```

Comment: thanks, tried that... also removed the ' before and after $_value ...
But nothing happened, no class name shows up. any idea?

Comment: I followed your link. This is not what I'm looking for. But I've tried it too, without success, further it creates unwanted content I don't really need/want (performance).

Comment: instead of  $_value->getTitle()  can you use $_option->getid()

Comment: How did you fix it? was it cache issue?

Comment: no, it's been related to a module I'm using.... so I changed that file instead...work in progress...